# The rule of adding a prepositional complementary phrase to a clause

Tags: grammar

*We can see that sole parents and their children were most likely to live in poverty, **with a poverty rate of around 21%**.*

In the above sentence, is the bolded phrase, including the comma, grammatical? Should there be a comma or not?

As the title suggests, I'm not really sure when I can add a prepositional phrase like this to the preceding clause to complement it, and I'm scared of making mistakes. So any improvement here is very much appreciated.

Comment: Does the phrase mean that 2 in 10 sole parents with children end up living in poverty, or that sole parents with children account for 21 percent of the impoverished population?  I assume the former, because of "rate".

Comment: Yes, it's the former.

Comment: It's OK to append such a supplementary phrase.  But since it's not necessary for the sense, it wouldn't be considered a grammatical complement.

Comment: "In the above sentence, is the bolded phrase, including the comma, grammatical? Should there be a comma or not?" Are these two separate questions? Are you worried about anything apart from the comma? (Note that questions about comma usage aren't usually related to grammar.)

Comment: @StuartF Yes, they are two separate questions. I meant to say I wasn't sure about two things. The first one is if adding a phrase like that is natural in writing. The second is whether there should be a comma before the phrase or not.

Comment: @TimR So readers would find the sentence grammatical and natural until they were informed that the author's intention was to use the phrase as a complement? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: Just saying that the phrase is not a complement in the grammatical sense of the term. You could begin the sentence with it: "With a poverty rate of 21%, single parents and their children are the most likely to live in poverty."  It supplies additional info. You could put it after the subject: "Single parents and their children, with a poverty rate of 21%, are the most likely to live in poverty".

Comment: Thank you! I got it. But I have another question, in your two latest examples, it seems that you removed the "we can see that" part intentionally. It makes me feel like if we included it, it would be wrong. For example, is this sentence incorrect: _With a poverty rate of 21%, we can see that single parents and their children are the most likely to live in poverty._?

Comment: It sounds wrong to me. If that's really the case, it seems that the position where you put the supplementary phrase actually matters since I didn't see you point out that my original sentence, where I put the phrase at the end, is incorrect.

Comment: Again, if that's the case, there must be a correlation between the supplementary phrase and the subject of the clause.

Comment: The phrase **with a poverty rate of 21%**  does apply to "single parents and their children".  So if you were going to include "we can see that" it must be placed appropriately.  *We can see that single parents and their children, with a poverty rate of 21%, are the most likely to live in poverty.*  And we could also put "with...21%" at the end of that sentence, but I think it's better right after the subject in the subordinate clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tim.